# How to convert a unmanaged double to a managed string?

Tags: c++, double, unmanaged, managed

From managed C++, I am calling an unmanaged C++ method which returns a double. How can I convert this double into a managed string?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I assume something like

```
(gcnew System::Double(d))->ToString()
```

Comment: Short and concised, thanks! Note: It should be (gcnew System::Double(d))->ToString() instead, but close enough.

Answer (score 2):

C++ is definitely not my strongest skillset.  Misread the question, but this should convert to a std::string, not exactly what you are looking for though, but leaving it since it was the original post....

```
double d = 123.45;
std::ostringstream oss;
oss << d;
std::string s = oss.str();
```

This should convert to a managed string however..

```
double d = 123.45
String^ s = System::Convert::ToString(d);
```